# Error:(44) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'nome do meu pacote'

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá,

Quando abro o meu projeto, ocorre o seguinte erro:
Error:(44) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package.
E o R do meu layout, não acha os layouts e com isso todas as minhas classes ficam com erro.
Segue algumas imagens:
[image: Mensagem do erro]
[image: R fica vermelho nas classes]

XML de uma das activities (list_layout_mensagem)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dfedd6"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUsuario"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDatas"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Data" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTexto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewUsuario"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fbtnRespMensagem"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbtnRespMensagem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewDatas"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTexto"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="respostaMensagem"
            app:backgroundTint="#2397f3"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Já procurei em vários lugares, e nada de solução :/

Comment: Verifique a existência de erros no layout *list_layout_mensagem*.

Comment: @ramaral Já verifiquei, e não apresenta erro. Não sei se você reparou, mas, todos os layouts estão com esse problema.

Comment: Isso é por causa da classe R. Adicione à pergunta o código do layout *list_layout_mensagem*.

Comment: @ramaral XML adicionado.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente o erro está em `app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"`.

Com a informação disponibilizada não me é possível saber a razão.

Para já, pode resolver o problema substituindo

```
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
```

por

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
```

Comment: ramaral, fiz aqui e agora resultou no erro Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'.

Comment: Onde está a usar roundIcon?

Comment: Estive procurando o roundIcon, mas, não encontrei nada e não me lembro de ter usado algo com este nome.

Comment: Faça um Clean Project em `Build`->`Clean Project`

Comment: Fiz o clean, e depois o rebuild... persiste o erro :/

Comment: Tem de encontrar onde `roundIcon` está a ser usado, O melhor é dar esta pergunta como resolvida e depois fazer outra pergunta, já que é outro problema.